# How to make singleton members threadsafe

Tags: c#, multithreading, singleton

Let's say I have the following singleton:

```
public sealed class singleton
{
// fields, creation, etc.
private static IList<SomeObjectType> _objects = new List<SomeObjectType>();
private ManualResetEvent _updateCompleted = new ManualResetEvent(true);

private bool RefreshRequired()
{
    //true if records in DB newer than the objects in the list
}

private void RefreshList()
{
    _updateCompleted.Reset();

    //code to refresh the list

    _updateCompleted.Set();
}

public IList<SomeObjectType> Objects
{
    get
    {
        _updateCompleted.Wait();

        if (RefreshRequired())
            RefreshList();

        return _objects;
    }
}

..
```

This way I am trying to achieve that data stored in the list is always up to date before any client reads it. This mechanism is very simple, but it is working well so far. However, obviously it is not sufficient for multithreading scenarios.
If there were multiple threads accessing the Objects-Member, I wanted only the first one to check if data is up to date and, then update the List if necessary. While the refresh is in progress, all other threads should be forced to wait BEFORE even checking if an refresh is required.
I have read much ablut locks, BlockedCollections, and ManualResetEvents, but I am not sure about which concept to use.

Could you explain which one you would choose and how you would solve the described task?

Comment: The _objects variable does not need any help since it is created by the static constructor.  There is no simple way to make the Objects property thread-safe, you don't know when the client code stops using the return value.  Only the client code can do it correctly.  Passing the job off to a programmer that's least likely to get it right is one of the core reasons why writing thread-safe code is so difficult.

Comment: The whole concept of "thread safe" is itself [only vaguely-defined](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx). Your first step is to figure out what _exactly_ you actually mean by that. "Always up to date" is also similarly vague; there will always be race conditions...you need to decide what behavior you want in such cases. What if new data is made available while "the first one" is in the process of updating the list? What should other threads see then? That's just scratching the surface...you have a lot of work ahead.

Comment: Okay, maybe the term 'thread safe' is too much (or wrong) for what I actually want. After reading the linked article, Peter, I would say that I just want other threads to be blocked while the list is being refreshed.

Comment: I have also tried to figure out, what you mean with 'only the client code can do it correctly', Hans, but I do not get the point. Is it, that there could be one thread using the return value while another one finds out, that the list is not up to date?

Comment: You are not looking for a ThreadSave Singelton. You want to use a ThreadSave Collection ( A singelton would be a Single Instance of an class that provides you more then a Collection does ). You are looking for something like a [ConcurrentBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx). Also Possible( if you would like to stay by your Desgin), you could do the simple Lock and Wrap up every access that is made to your Collection if your are Intrested i post an example

Comment: Yes, JP, this is exactly what I want (and what I have written in the topic btw :) ). However, I am not sure if the ConcurrentBag or BlockingCollection can do the job since I also want to block other threads from entering RefreshRequired(). Maybe I am wrong, but I think the lock-statement would create a bottle-neck. I think, when there is no update in progress, everything is fine and no block is needed. This is why my first approach was to solve that by using a ManualResetEvent. This event was reset within the Update-Method and set when it was finished, but it didn't work :( How would you lock?

Comment: .. I have added the mentioned ManualResetEvent-approach to my code just to give you an idea of what I had tried. However, it seems to be too "slow" .. when the event is reset, other threads may have entered already. So my approach is insufficient.

Comment: Oh, and there is no need to keep that design .. if you could give an advice, that would be absolutely great :)

Answer (score -1):

Best answer i can suggest is found here: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Since I'll get yelled at by the masses if only posting a link, here are some samples taken from the article to ponder. The article largely has to do with performance, and appropriateness so please read it's descriptions of these samples.

As far as your Refresh method, the others commented on that fairly well. It's just as important knowing how it's intended to be consumed.

Hopefully the article gives you some food for thought.

Simple thread safety...

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance = null;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thread-safe without using locks...

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
    // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static Singleton()
    {
    }

    private Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Fully lazy instantiation...

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return Nested.instance; } }

    private class Nested
    {
        // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
        // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
        static Nested()
        {
        }

        internal static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    }
}
```

Using .NET 4's Lazy type...

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy =
        new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private Singleton()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This is in no way solving the problem described in the question.

Comment: Servy is right, but thanks for your efforts, Atoms. I do know about the singleton pattern and its implementation and, thus, didn't mention it above .. if the timespan between the first thread entering and other ones is big enough, the ManualResetEvent should perform okay, but if there are threads entering almost simultaneously, this mechanism is just to slow - at least this is what it seems to me.